# Calendar Picker doesn't let pick a date (if calling setState or parent functions)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I've got a CalendarPicker *react-native-calendar-picker* on a Modal, and **it let's me select a date normally if I have nothing but a `console.log(date)`** on it's `onDateChange`, but when it's function calls `this.setState` or `this.props.changeDate`, **it doesn't change visually it's selection, but it logs well the new date.**

**Code**
**Constructor of the modal (child)**

```js
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { fecha: moment() };
 this.onDateChange = this.onDateChange.bind(this);//Copied this from docs, tried with and without it
}
```

**CalendarPicker inside the modal (child)**

```js
<CalendarPicker
 width={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.3}
 height={Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.55}
 months={months} //Custom months in Spanish
 weekdays={weekdays} //Custom weekdays in Spanish
 previousTitle={"Anterior mes"} //Custom previous title in Spanish
 previousTitleStyle={[
 {
  backgroundColor: colors.darkBackground,
  padding: 6,
  borderRadius: 10,
 },
 ]}
 nextTitle={"Siguiente mes"} //Custom next title in Spanish
 nextTitleStyle={[
 {
  backgroundColor: colors.darkBackground,
  padding: 6,
  borderRadius: 10,
 },
 ]}
 startFromMonday={true} //Start from monday
 textStyle={[globalStyles.blackText, { margin: 0, padding: 0 }]} //Style for text
 todayBackgroundColor={"transparent"} //Don't give any color to today's day
 selectedDayColor={colors.successColor} //Color to selected day
 selectedStartDate={moment()} //Start from today's date
 onDateChange={this.onDateChange}/>
```

**onDateChange function on modal (child)**

```js
onDateChange = (date) => {
 console.log(date);//It logs well the new date "2020-07-09T10:00:00.000Z"
 this.setState({ fecha: date });//If I comment this, the selection works, uncommented it doesn't
};
```

**Close button on the modal (child)**

```js
onPress={() => {
 let s = this.state.fecha.toString();
 this.props.changeDate(s);//Calls the parent's changeDate function
 onCloseModal();//Just closes the modal
}}
```

**CalendarPickerModal on parent**

```js
<CalendarPickerModal
 onRef={(ref) => (this.Option = ref)}
 visible={this.state.calendarModalVisible}
 onCloseModal={this.toggleCalendarModal}
 changeDate={() => this.changeDate()}
/>
```

**ChangeDate() on parent**

```js
changeDate(date) {
 self.setState({ dateIn: date });
 console.log("INFOMODAL", date);//It logs well the new date "INFOMODAL Thu Jul 09 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0200"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the prop `selectedStartDate={moment()} //Start from today's date` of the `CalendarPicker`, at start I didn't put it on the question because I didn't think that would be the problem, but after some tries I found the solution. Just removing this line I can pick the day correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the date update in your modal, why don't you just do :

**CalendarPickerModal on parent**

Just assign your `changeDate` function to the `changeDate` prop.
It will avoid having a useless arrow function.

```
<CalendarPickerModal
 onRef={(ref) => (this.Option = ref)}
 visible={this.state.calendarModalVisible}
 onCloseModal={this.toggleCalendarModal}
 changeDate={this.changeDate}
/>
```

**CalendarPicker inside the modal (child)**

Pass your modal prop `changeDate` to your *CalenderPicker* prop `onDateChange`.

```
<CalendarPicker 
 ...
 onDateChange={this.props.changeDate}
/>
```

With this model you get rid of intermediate state and even your modal constructor.

Comment: About the first comment, it's true. I did it already.

Comment: Did it change the result? And why don't you use this.setState instead of self.setState?

Comment: It didn't change the result.
About the second option in your answer, what I want is to **change only when I close the modal**, not every time I change the date. 
I've still tried it, just to see if it works, and with both your code and `onDateChange={(date) => this.props.changeDate(date)}` it gives an error: `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child, if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`.
And I'm using self.setState (`self=this` on the constructor) because 'this' on a function refers to the function itself, not to the class